# search book for particular category with Google book API V1

Tags: android, google-books

With Google Book Search API V1 i am able to search books.

Now I want to search only specific category books whenever user try to search with different keywords.

I am not able to set category within Book API V1 https://developers.google.com/books/docs/overview?csw=1.

please let me know if anyone have idea about this.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [subject](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#WorkingVolumes) search keyword. Something like

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:adventure&key=yourAPIKey
```

should work

Comment: do you know how to download pdf from Downloadlink key?